# C# Install application ResolveComReference failed

Tags: c#, exception, installation, windows-installer, filenotfoundexception

I developed application and tried to install it on another PC (same PC as mine developer PC)
I installed the application and nothing run , I've tried to debug it with Visual studio
and I've got the error as following:

> The "ResolveComReference" task failed un expectedly.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0' or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0'

I have same .net framework version 4.5.1 on my PCS
What should I do / install to make it work?
Thanks for help

Comment: This error message has nothing to do with installing or debugging.  It is generated when you *build* a program, note the words "Microsoft.Build" in the error message.  Why you cannot build is entirely unclear, re-installing VS is the obvious next thing to try.  Forgetting to deploy the COM component you use is the most obvious reason you'd have trouble running your program.  Never forget to write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException so you can diagnose runtime failure without a debugger.

Comment: Thanks for your comment , I have UnhandledException , but when I install my application , and try to run it. There is no exceptions or something like this, Its just run , start at process bar and close it self immediately, what the problem might be ? @HansPassant